# How to get the position of a row when a MYSQL table is ordered

Tags: php, sql-order-by

I want to find the position of a row when I order the table in a descending order. I used the following to order the rows in a descending order.

```
SELECT * FROM feature Order BY Votes DESC
```

I need to find what position the row is in compared to others, such as 1st, 5th, 8th... 
I was thinking of using a loop that loops through each value in the ordered from greatest to lowest and if the votes are greater than the previous value but more than the next value, then the position can be found. However, I found this to be impractical if there are many rows in the table. How can I find the relative standing of a row? A simple direction will be sufficient.

Comment: Simplest way (IMHO) is to number them as you fetch them from the database n PHP.  So each 'fetch' may either put them in an array or just add a value to the returned values which is an incremented value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could loop through the result as an assoc array, with an $i variable increased each iteration. That $i variable would tell you each row's position in order.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM feature Order BY Votes DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$i = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id = $row['idColumnName'];
    if ($id == 'idNumber'){
        echo("My ID is: ".$id." and I am voted number: ".$i);
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: How can I use this to find the standing of a random id? Is there a way to order the table then find the row I am searching for an echo its position such as 5th. I don't need the positions of other rows, only the one whose id is being searched for. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've updated my answer to handle that. Just change 'idColumnName' and 'idNumber' to what you are looking for. Know that the while loop cycles through each row at a time, so you can grab whatever information you want from each row, or use an if statement to find a certain match. Inside the while loop, you can use $row['columnName'] to find the value of any column you want. In your case, the id column.